# image uploading directive angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to writing directives in Angular and was following along with the egghead tutorial on file uploaders, and managed to get my file uploader to work with express/multer.  I have this really weird behavior though--- once the file is chosen, one of those ugly default image shows up:

[image: ugly alt image showing up--why?]

When I click "upload" everything is fine (except for Kim Kardashian of course):

[image]

Here is my angular code. I think everything is working fine on the server side:

Controller/Directive:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, Profile) {
    // $rootScope.currentUser = user;
    $scope.user = $rootScope.currentUser;
    $scope.name = $scope.user.name;
    $scope.imageData = null;
    $scope.pictures = $scope.user.facebook ? $scope.user.facebook.pictures : $scope.imageData;

    // console.log($scope.user);
    $scope.filesChanged = function (elm) {
      $scope.files = elm.files;
      $scope.apply();
    };

    $scope.upload = function () {
      var fd = new FormData();
      angular.forEach($scope.files, function (file) {
        fd.append('file', file);
      });

      $http.post('upload', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined
        }

      }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.imageData = data;
        console.log($scope.imageData);
      });
    };
  })
  .directive('fileInput', ['$parse',
    function ($parse) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
          elm.bind('change', function () {
            $parse(attrs.fileInput)
              .assign(scope, elm[0].files);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

html:

```
<center>
    <h3>Your Profile</h3>
</center>
<h4 class="col-sm-2 sidebar">{{name}} </h4>
<div class="col sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 sidebar" ng-if="user.facebook">
    <img data-ng-src="{{pictures}}">
</div>
<div>

    <br> Change Your Profile Picture:
    <br>
    <form ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
        <input type="file" file-input="files" multiple />
        <button ng-click="upload()">Upload</button>
        <li ng-repeat="file in files">{{file.name}}
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{imageData}}">
        <button ng-click="saveImage()">
            Save New Profile Picture
        </button>
        </li>
    </form>
</div>
```

In addition to this specific issue, I'm not grasping at a high level what the purpose of the directive is. why couldn't I just ng-repeat with data returned from the '/upload' route in multer?

UPDATE:

thanks to @jontewks, I figured it out. For some reason I declared `$scope.imageData = null`

in the top of my controller. once I removed that it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the image doesn't show up until you hit upload is that the  is looking for {{imageData}} on the $scope but that isn't available until the .success of the http.post happens. See if there is a way to use the file data before uploading occurs and that will solve the issue.